# Restkit request not sending parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

My implementation is not sending parameters. Here is the RequestDescriptor:

```
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"nombres", @"telefono", @"direccion", @"email", @"identificacion", @"tipo_id", @"recibir_sms_ordenes", @"recibir_correos_ordenes"]];
RKRequestDescriptor *descriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping objectClass:[RKUser class] rootKeyPath:@"me" method:RKRequestMethodAny];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:descriptor];
```

Here is the post request:

```
RKUser *user = [self currentUser].user;     // [self currentUser].user returns the current RKUser
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager postObject:user path:@"/api/me.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
  NSLog(@"%@ %@", operation, mappingResult);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, operation);
}];
```

In the server, I only receive one empty `current_user` parameter. Any ideas on why?

PD. The server expects JSON payload under `me` key

Comment: What do you mean 'parameter'? What does the server expect to receive? Did you set the request serialisation type to JSON?

Comment: @Wain how do I do that? The server expects the object in JSON Maybe that's what I'm missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have set:

```
manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

As the default is `RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded`.

---

Based on your comments and discussion, the mapping isn't being used because the class of the user is wrong. This is because it is a plain `NSManagedObject` rather than an `RKUser` instance. This means RestKit can't find the appropriate mapping. The cause for this is the custom class not being set on the `User` entity in your Core Data model.

Comment: I already did that, but it keeps sending nothing to the server. What am I missing? Thanks for your answer, BTW

Comment: So, what is `RKUser`? What properties? Turn on trace logging for the mapping and see what it tells you.

Comment: `RKUser` has the following properties: `@[@"nombres", @"telefono", @"direccion", @"email", @"identificacion", @"tipo_id", @"recibir_sms_ordenes", @"recibir_correos_ordenes"]` (the same I add on the mapping). I already set `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);` and it shows nothing about the mapping. Maybe it isn't hitting that requestMapping

Comment: The log should say something about the mapping, even if it just tells you it doesn't understand the class (there is no matching mapping).

Comment: But I am setting the requestMapping correctly, am I? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The code you have shown looks ok, that's why the log is so important. The class of the object could be wrong. Or the mapping may be created before the manager is set. But I can't tell from the current information...

Comment: Is there a way to manually set the mapping on the `RKUser` before doing the post?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42973/discussion-between-wain-and-macool)