# Unable to map the fields to JSON and JSON to fields in class RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, restkit

I have following code where I am calling a RESTful API and register a user, but it gives me error as mentioned below

```
 // Construct a request mapping for our class
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"strFirstName": @"FirstName", @"strLastName": @"LastName",@"strEmail":@"Email",@"strPhoneNumber":@"PhoneNumber",@"strToken":@"Token",@"strPassword":@"Password" }];

// We wish to generate parameters of the format:
// @{"Client":{"FirstName":"String","LastName":"String","Email":"String","Password":"String","PhoneNumber":"String","Token":"String"}}
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                               objectClass:[Client class]
                                                                               rootKeyPath:@"Client" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

// Construct an object mapping for the response
// We are expecting JSON in the format:
//{"Client":{"FirstName":"String","LastName":"String","Email":"String","Password":"String","PhoneNumber":"String","Token":"String"},"ErrorMessage":"String","FriendlyMessage":"String"}
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Client class]];

[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"FirstName": @"strFirstName", @"LastName": @"strLastName",@"Email":@"strEmail",@"PhoneNumber":@"strPhoneNumber",@"Token":@"strToken",@"Password":@"strPassword" }];

// Construct a response descriptor that matches any URL (the pathPattern is nil), when the response payload
// contains content nested under the `@"page"` key path, if the response status code is 200 (OK)
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                   method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:@"Client"
                                                                                   statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
   // Register our descriptors with a manager
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"BASE_URL"]];

[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

// Work with the object
Client *client = [Client new];
NewUser *user = [NewUser sharedNewUser];
client.strFirsName = user.strFname;
client.strLastName = user.strLname;
client.strPassword = user.strPwd;
client.strPhoneNumber = user.strNum;
client.strEmail = user.strEmail;

// POST the parameterized representation of the `page` object to `/posts` and map the response
[manager postObject:client path:@"/services/servicestack/RegisterClient.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"We object mapped the response with the following result: %@", result);
} failure:nil];
```

Also the client class

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "RESTObject.h"

   @interface Client : RESTObject
   {
    NSString *strFirstName;
    NSString *strLastName;
    NSString *strEmail;
    NSString *strPassword;
    NSString *strPhoneNumber;
    NSString *strToken;

   }

   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strFirsName;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strLastName;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strEmail;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strPassword;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strPhoneNumber;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strToken;

   @end
```

RESTObject class

```
@interface RESTObject : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strErrorMessage;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *strFriendlyMessage;

@end
```

Error that I am getting is as follows

```
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:243 POST 'http://101.178.90.12/chauffr_services/servicestack/RegisterClient.json' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.7125s mapping=0.0000s total=0.7358s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0x78e88e40 {DetailedErrors=(
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: Client
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: ErrorMessage
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., keyPath=null}
```

The expected input JSON is

> POST /json/reply/RegisterClientRequest HTTP/1.1  Host: 101.178.90.12 
>   Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: length
>
> {"Client":{"FirstName":"String","LastName":"String","Email":"String","Password":"String","PhoneNumber":"String","Token":"String"}}

expected output JSON is

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: length
>
> {"Client":{"FirstName":"String","LastName":"String","Email":"String","Password":"String","PhoneNumber":"String","Token":"String"},"ErrorMessage":"String","FriendlyMessage":"String"}

I might be making some very silly mistake but I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is:

```
The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: Client
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: ErrorMessage
```

So while you are expecting the response to contain 'Client' data, it doesn't, it contains an 'Error', so RestKit can't find anything that you have asked it to process.

Obviously you need to find out why yhe server returns an error, but you can also add an error mapping, or, more likely if the success status code is always returned, use a dynamic mapping to choose what to do and then use the mapped keypath to handle appropriately.

Comment: Do you see any error / problem with request mapping ? You are correct server doesn't find client object at input , i tested it and error message is always there

Comment: It looks ok. Have you configured to use a JSON serialiser? I guess you're sending form encoded...

Comment: No i don't think i need to separately configure serializer it by default does it in JSON

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509963/restkit-request-not-sending-parameters

Comment: That just worked , and JSON now gets posted service works but reverse mapping fails and returns nothing .