# RESTKit: Error with POST Request (Loaded an unprocessable error response (400))

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I try to make this command by using RESTKit

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"rgb":{"cwhite":0,"wwhite":0,"red":22222,"blue":0,"green":22222},"period":1000}' http://192.168.8.7/config?command=light
```

This is my Code

**Mapping Class**

```
@interface LightState : NSObject

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) NSInteger period;
@property (strong, nonatomic) LightRGB *rgb;
@end

@interface LightRGB : NSObject

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) NSInteger red;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) NSInteger green;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) NSInteger blue;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) NSInteger cwhite;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) NSInteger wwhite;
@end
```

**Post Request Code**

```
LightState * state = [LightState new];
    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Open"]) {

        state.period = 1000;
        state.rgb.red = 0;
        state.rgb.green = 0;
        state.rgb.blue = 0;
        state.rgb.cwhite = 0;
        state.rgb.wwhite = 0;
    }else{

        state.period = 1000;
        state.rgb.red = 22222;
        state.rgb.green = 22222;
        state.rgb.blue = 22222;
        state.rgb.cwhite = 22222;
        state.rgb.wwhite = 22222;
    }

    //ObjectMapping
    RKObjectMapping *lightMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [lightMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"period":@"period"}];

    RKObjectMapping *lightRGBMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [lightRGBMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"red":@"red",@"green":@"green",@"blue":@"blue",@"cwhite":@"cwhite",@"wwhite":@"wwhite"}];
    [lightMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"rgb"
                                                                                 toKeyPath:@"rgb"
                                                                               withMapping:lightRGBMapping]];

    RKRequestDescriptor *lightRD = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:lightMapping objectClass:[LightState class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    //URL
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",self.deviceIP];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];

    RKObjectManager *obj = [[RKObjectManager alloc]initWithHTTPClient:client];

    [obj addRequestDescriptor:lightRD];


    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

    //post
    [obj postObject:state path:@"/config?command=light" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        NSLog(@"lightToggleHandler Success");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"lightToggleHandler Failure header\n%@ body\n%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.request.allHTTPHeaderFields,operation.HTTPRequestOperation.request.HTTPBody);
    }];
}
```

Here are `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);` printed

```
request.headers={
    "Accept-Language" = "zh-TW;q=1, en-TW;q=0.9, zh-Hans-TW;q=0.8, ja-TW;q=0.7";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "LightController/1 (iPhone; iOS 9.3.2; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=period=1000&rgb[blue]=0&rgb[cwhite]=0&rgb[green]=0&rgb[red]=0&rgb[wwhite]=0
```

Request body looks right ,but Server return error

```
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Loaded an unprocessable error response (400)"
```

Where is wrong? Anyone have any ideas to do it correctly?

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509963/restkit-request-not-sending-parameters

Comment: It change the Content-Type to JSON,but it still return 400 error. Here are the logs return request.body={"rgb":{"cwhite":0,"wwhite":0,"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0},"period":1000}

Comment: so you need to show what is actually sent (use charles to check)

Comment: I check the header Setting and body by PostMan,it works great. So I really don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: you mean you use postman to test the server? you need to check that the app is actually sending to the network

Comment: sorry for my wrong understanding of your point. I check app client packet ,that is actually sending to the network.Then I try to send the post again and again.I find out that is success once every 10 times.